Sharing macros Apps script on Sheets
For the past 2 years, I've created a Sheet file with macros coded in Apps Scripts, and I was able to share them without any issues with other users. Since this week, other users can no longer activate the scripts (via a click on an image) - they get : "Problem: Function xxx cannot be found" error, for all functions, even though the Apps Script code is properly shared...
Do you know how to fix this problem and share the macros with all Editor users of the spreadsheet?
I didn't have this problem last month.
Thank you for your help.
I tried to change the permissions, but nothing works.
